# Conforming Array to Equatable for certain non-equatable types

Tags: swift, generics

Note: I think people are missing the point of this question, it's not about me having an array where the element is a protocol, and it's probably not even about conditionally conforming something to `Equatable` specifically; these are just the examples I'm using. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be possible to conditionally-conform something to a protocol multiple times (with different conditions).

---

When Swift 4.1 was announced with conditional conformance, I was looking forward to having arrays and dictionaries conform to `Equatable` when their elements did. In addition, I have some arrays of a custom protocol (called `AnyDataType`) which defines its own comparison function to allow comparing between any two `AnyDataType` variables, even if they're of different concrete types:

```
protocol AnyDataType {
    func isEqual(to otherDataType: AnyDataType) -> Bool
}
```

I was hoping I might make `Array<AnyDataType>` conform to `Equatable` by adding an additional conformance:

```
extension Array: Equatable where Element == AnyDataType {
    static func == (lhs: [AnyDataType], rhs: [AnyDataType]) -> Bool {
        ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. While it does compile, I get the following warning:

> Conformance of 'Array' to protocol 'Equatable' was already stated in the type's module 'Swift'

And it doesn't actually make `Array<AnyDataType>` conform to `Equatable` anyway (e.g. you can't compare two `[[AnyDataType]]`s). Is there anything different I need to do, or is this just not possible?

---

Note that this has nothing to do with it being an array of protocols. I had the same problems trying to conform an array of custom, non-`Equatable` structs as well.

Comment: I can't conform `AnyDataType` to `Equatable` because it doesn't allow comparing *any* two `AnyDataType`s (i.e, you have to know the concrete type).

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the fact I'm using an array of protocols anyway, see the note at the bottom. The issue I'm having is probably because Swift doesn't appear to allow multiple conditional conformances to the same protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this is an intended restriction, according to [SE-0143](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md#detailed-design), but it might be something which is allowed in the future.

For now, depending on the desired usage, the best solutions are probably:

- If you wanted to conform to `Equatable` so that `==` would work, you can just implement the `==` on the specialised collections directly without the conformance (and add an implementation for `!=` which just negates that result). This is satisfactory for me for the time being.
- If you wanted to have collections of your type actually conform to `Equatable` where the type itself can't (because it's e.g. a protocol), type erasure [might be an option](https://forums.swift.org/t/not-possible-to-conditionally-conform-something-to-a-protocol-multiple-times/11691/6).

Answer (score -2):

There's no way to do accomplish what you want.

Comment: I can't conform `AnyDataType` to `Equatable` because you can't for example do: `var a: AnyDataType = …; var b: AnyDataType = …; a == b`

Comment: What does this mean, then: *which defines its own comparison function to allow comparing between any two `AnyDataType` variables*.

Comment: So I have a protocol called `AnyDataType`, and I conform things like `Int`, `String`, `Float`, and other custom structs to it. If I have two `AnyDataType` variables, I can't compare them using `Equatable` because they have to be guaranteed the same type first. I couldn't even have a `AnyDataType` variable in the first place if it conformed to `Equatable` because that's a compile error ('Protocol `AnyDataType` can only be used as a generic constrict because it has Self or associated type requirements')

Comment: If you still don't understand, try implementing your suggesting in Playground; you'll see it won't compile.